# problem with search

Tags: asp.net

Hey, I've a search in website. If i search for a particular world it works fine in all pages but not in contact us. contact us page contains validation controls. I tried with removing validation controls, then the search works fine. any help on these how to make search though validation controls, are present.

function KeyPress(txt)
       {
          //alert(txt);
           if(txt == "Search")
           {                            
               document.getElementById("ctl00_txtSearch").value = "";
            }
        }

       function OnBlur(txt)
       {

        if(txt == "")
        {
          document.getElementById("ctl00_txtSearch").value = "Search";
          // txtSearch.style.color = "silver";
        }
       } 

       function button_onclick()
      {
        if(document.getElementById("").value == "" ||                              document.getElementById("").value == "Search ")
       {
         document.getElementById("").focus();
         alert("Please Enter Text");
          return false;
        }
      }

Comment: you really need to show some code, what your currently seeing, and what you expect to see. this current question is unanswerable.

Comment: please say on when it is called.Please give the same way as u write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do validation group for each page and for each set of controls. Another things you can do the third party search component like following.

http://www.sitesearchasp.net/

try this.

Answer (score 0):

Please put Validation Group of validation controls to some value and in the case of search button give another name for validation group.I hope it will work for u.

```
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Date" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDate"                                                                           ErrorMessage="Please give a Date here" ValidationGroup="Group" ForeColor="White">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

     <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSave" runat="server"  
                                    ValidationGroup="Group">Save</asp:LinkButton>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSearch" runat="server"  
                                    ValidationGroup="abc">Search</asp:LinkButton>
```

For search button you put some other validation group.